# Remote client IP address in Flask

Tags: python, flask

How can I get the remote / client IP in Flask running on Apache? My webservice is behind a load balancer, so `request.remote_addr` gives the load balancer IP instead of the client IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the remote client ip like this:

```
remote_ip = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For')
if not remote_ip:
    remote_ip = request.remote_addr
```

alternative method:

```
remote_ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
if not remote_ip:
    remote_ip = request.environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your balancer is [rf7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239) compliant it should send a `Forwarded` header, if it's not, it might send `X-Forwarded-For`. Check any of these headers instead of `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: Not working, Looks like i need to do some apache settings.

Comment: I think Apache+mod_proxy sends `X-Forwarded-For`. Maybe WSGI is messing with the headers? . Let me go through `werkzeug` code and come back to you.

Comment: @JamesSapam, nope, it is definetly something in your balancer.

Comment: Ok will checkout and let u know if i find something.